How to proxy url's in an img tag in Nuxt 3
I have a nuxt app paired to a Directus backend for the database and images hosting.
Directus has an endpoint to access the database: https://mydirectus.com/items/myCollection
I proxy this api using the server folder in Nuxt. That way, the url of the api is not publicly exposed.  The url appears as https://myfrontend.com/api/items.
But, how can I do the same thing for the image url's?
Directus has an endpint for assets: https://mydirectus.com/assets/myImageId
That is the url I can use in the  tags.
But I don't want them to be exposed. if I use the same technique as I use for the /items endpoint, it doesn't work because, I think, the  tag is not asynchronous.
So how can I proxy those url pointing to images stored in Directus ?

Was server folder not working for images?  Did you try https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt-proxy ? You may consider a smarter approach that will cache fetched files, something like https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/discussions/561
